# FTP Server not accepting connections despite port being open

Tags: vpn, ftp, port-forwarding, filezilla

I'm working on setting up an FTP server, due to my situation I am working through a VPN (Mullvad) and using their port-forwarding feature to open specific ports (this definitely works as I have it working with a Minecraft server and another application). I am using FileZilla Server after trying and failing with the default windows setup.

I seem to have set up port-forwarding properly, as the port registers as open with [yougetsignal](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) and like I said I've done this before and it worked. I have the server configured to connect on the open port and it works fine locally.

When I use [ftptest](https://ftptest.net/) to specifically test if the ftp works I get the following: `Error: Could not read from socket: Connection reset by peer` (I am also unable to connect with my local filezilla client as well as another online ftp client) This is different than the error I get if I try a random port: `Error: Could not connect to server: Connection refused`.

As far as I know I have set up my firewall, VPN and server properly as tests for each show that they work (VPN & Firewall; port is open & FileZilla server; local connection on the port works) but a combination of both somehow causes issues.

Any help would be much appreciated as I am at somewhat of a loss at this point.

Comment: when you say FTP port open - you have forwarded both 20 and 21?

Comment: I changed the port that the server is using for FTP to 59941 and that is forwarded, I cannot use the defaults ports due to the VPN as I mentioned, is there a second port I need to change somewhere else as well? @Zina

Comment: [see this nice explanation](https://www.jscape.com/blog/bid/80512/active-v-s-passive-ftp-simplified) - so you will need to check your FTP server settings and configure your port forward properly